# How to overwrite in my previous excel file using JXL?

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I want to set the status of executing test but whenever I execute the code it create new workbook by using this line:

```
wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath));
```

Now can anyone please let me know how I can set the status of executing test case.

For this I am using JXL lib. and in keydriven framework.

Below are the code of write in excel:

```
 public class MainClass {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\softs\\FF installed\\FF18\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String TEST_SUITE_PATH = "D:\\GmailTestSuite.xls";
    private static final String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH = "D:\\objectrepository.xls";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Properties properties;

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        main.handleTestSuite();
    }

    private void handleTestSuite() throws Exception {
        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile = new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();
        ExcelHandler testSuite = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount = testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String executable = testSuite.readCell(
                    testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable=" + executable);

            if (executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // exe. the process
                String scenarioName = testSuite.readCell(
                        testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);
                System.out.println("Scenario Name=" + scenarioName);
                handleScenario(scenarioName);
            }
        }
        WritableData writableData= new WritableData(TEST_SUITE_PATH,"Login");
        writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 1, "Pass");
        writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 2, "Fail");
        writableData.shSheet("Login", 5, 3, "N/A");
    }

    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws Exception {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
        testScenarios.setSheetName("Login");
        testScenarios.columnData();
        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(
                    testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
            System.out.println("FRMNameKK=" + framWork + ",Operation="
                    + operation + ",Value=" + value);

            handleObjects(operation, value, framWork);
        }
    }

    private void handleObjects(String operation, String value, String framWork)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("HandleObject--> " + framWork);
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(
                OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows in hadleObject=" + rowCount);

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("FrameworkName"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(
                    objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            System.out.println("FrameWorkNameV=" + frameWorkName
                    + ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);

            if (framWork.equalsIgnoreCase(frameWorkName)) {
                operateWebDriver(operation, Locator, value, ObjectName);

            }
        }
    }

    private void operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
        WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
            temp.sendKeys(value);
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
            temp.click();
        }

        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
            System.out.println("Verify--->" +temp);
            temp.isDisplayed();
        }
    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;
        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

public class WritableData {

```
Workbook wbook;
WritableWorkbook wwbCopy;
String ExecutedTestCasesSheet;
WritableSheet shSheet;

public WritableData(String testSuitePath, String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


     try { wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath)); 
     wwbCopy= Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath),wbook);
     System.out.println("writable workbookC-->" +wwbCopy);
     shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login");
     System.out.println("writable sheetC-->" +shSheet); 
     //shSheet = wwbCopy.createSheet("Login", 1); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
         // TODO: handle exception 
         System.out.println("Exception message" + e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); } }

      public void shSheet(String strSheetName, int iColumnNumber, int
      iRowNumber, String strData) throws WriteException, IOException { 
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);
      shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login"); 

      WritableFont cellFont = null;
      WritableCellFormat cellFormat = null;

      if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) { cellFont = new
      WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
      cellFont.setColour(Colour.GREEN);
      cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

      cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
      cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN); }

      else if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) { cellFont = new
      WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12); cellFont.setColour(Colour.RED);
      cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

      cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
      cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN); }

      else { cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
      cellFont.setColour(Colour.BLACK);

      cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
      cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
      cellFormat.setWrap(true); }

      Label labTemp = new Label(iColumnNumber, iRowNumber, strData,
      cellFormat);
      shSheet.addCell(labTemp); 
      System.out.println("writableSheet---->"+shSheet);

      wwbCopy.write(); 
      wwbCopy.close();
      wbook.close();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with creating the excel by copying the existing one and then modifying as per needs.

```
    Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(Constant.wBook));
    WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(Constant.wBook), existingWorkbook);
    WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet("report");

    int step_num = col + 1;


    Label lb = new Label(0, col, Integer.toString(step_num));
    Label lb1 = new Label(1, col, text);
    Label lb2 = new Label(2, col, result);


    System.out.println(text + "" + result + "");

    sheetToEdit.addCell(lb);
    sheetToEdit.addCell(lb1);
    sheetToEdit.addCell(lb2);


    workbookCopy.write();
    workbookCopy.close();
    existingWorkbook.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't understand exactly I've edited my code above and can you please check my code and let me know where I do correction in it? Actually I am beginner and stuck because of these. :(

Comment: Yes seems to be OK. we do a copy of the existing excel for each iteration, modify and rewrite the excel.have enhanced my code, please check.

Comment: Giri Can you please edit your ans. according to my code, so it would be helpful for me to reach the goal early, because still its not writing the sheet.

Comment: You must close the wwbCopy as well after write in your code. Add  wwbCopy.close() after  wwbCopy.write(), Code seems to be fine. By this on each iteration it creates a excel by copying the existing excel and modifies.

Comment: In writableData class after one iteration it set or write the status pss but on second iteration it shows null at method "shSheet" on starting. So, can you please let me know for continuous iteration how to call object again or how to resolve it.